# Merge JavaScript code with its TypeScript definition from different files

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to use a specific file from a repository without installing its NPM package, but it was coded in JavaScript and has a separate definition file.

- [The code file in JavaScript](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/main/src/headers.js) exports a `Headers` class ()
- [The TypeScript definition file](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/main/%40types/index.d.ts) exports the `Headers` class definition

I want to merge the JavaScript implementation with the type definition, so I ended with this approach:

```js
import { default as HeadersImplementation } from '../node-fetch/src/headers.js';
import { Headers as HeadersDefinition, HeadersInit } from '../node-fetch/@types/index';

const Headers: {
  prototype: HeadersImplementation;
  new(init?: HeadersInit): HeadersDefinition;
} = HeadersImplementation;

const teste = new Headers();
teste.append('Hello', 'World!');
```

**Is there an easy way to merge the class implementation with its definition?**

Comment: "I want to use a specific file from a repository without installing its NPM package" why? "I want to merge the JavaScript implementation with the type definition" why? You don't need to do that just to consume the file and types in Typescript. Just add the .d.ts file in your types folder. None of this makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would re-export it so that using it is clean and straightforward in other modules:

> Don't forget to re-export the `HeadersInit` type so that you can strongly type a constructor input argument

`./src/headers.ts`:

```ts
// @ts-ignore
import {default as HeadersImplementation} from '../node-fetch/src/headers.js';
import {type Headers} from '../node-fetch/@types/index';
export {type HeadersInit} from '../node-fetch/@types/index';

const H: typeof Headers = HeadersImplementation;
export {H as Headers};
```

`./src/index.ts`:

```ts
import {Headers, type HeadersInit} from './headers.js';

const init: HeadersInit = [['name', 'value']];
const test = new Headers(init);
test.append('Hello', 'World!');
console.log([...test]);
```

```
$ tsc && node dist/index.js
[ [ 'hello', 'World!' ], [ 'name', 'value' ] ]
```

Comment: In case you haven't heard of Deno (https://deno.land), I think you would really enjoy using it.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to touch any part of that code, nor try to merge things in your own code. just have the two files with the same name and import in your code what you need.

you need just 2 installs in your project, which are possibly already in your project.

steps to follow:

- download/copy `js` file into a folder in your project
- download/copy `.d.ts` file into the same folder and rename it so both have the same names; i.g. `headers.js` and `headers.d.ts`
- install `typescript` if you haven't done so: `npm i -D typescript` (you possibly have already done so)
- install typings module: `npm install --save @types/node`
- go ahead and import whatever you want: `import {Headers} from "./headers.js"`
- enjoy the types in your own code

you can also:

- copy all the files in the `src` folder into a folder of your choice; `node-fetch` will serve better
- copy `index.d.ts` into this folder. voila! you will get types for node-fetch for everything defined in it.
- this time import from the folder: `import {Headers} from "./node-fetch"`